# overloading operator >>()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My knowledge of C++ is small as I have only taken a couple classes.  I undersand the basic case of using a friend function to overload the input, output stream operator for the "simple book example" of a Point object that has x, y instance variables.  I am looking at a real project now, trying to understand what someone wrote and am getting the error:

```
error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\istream(1000): could be 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

Noob question (1), can someone explain what basic_istream is?  The error points to:

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL  operator>>(
        basic_istream<char, _Traits>& _Istr, signed char *_Str)
    {   // extract a signed char NTBS
    return (_Istr >> (char *)_Str);
    }
```

The other part the error points to is:

```
void input(std::istream &in = std::cin)
    {in >> "(" >> X >> "," >> Y >> "," >> Z >> ")" ; }

inline friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Coord &val)
    {val.input(in); return in; };
```

Not sure what the error is looking at with my limited knowledge.  It seems to be complaining about not the right type in the inline friend std::istream& operator>> function because of something wrong in the basic_istream template (which I'm not sure what is happening there).  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: _Never_ __undersand__ the basic case of using a friend...whatever that means. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

First off, since you are new to C++: Do not trust the compiler error messages too much. In complicated code (templates, overloading...) you frequently get messages that are unrelated to the real issue.

Incorporating the comment on my answer: In your case though, the "," and similar objects are const, and the operator for the X, Y, Z is only declared on non-const objects, therefore not applicable. You'd either have to duplicate it, or only write a const version.

Comment: String literals are const, so yes, the "(", ")", and the "," are const.

Comment: In this case it is directly related to the real issue: no `operator>>` takes a stream on the left and `const char[2]` on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't parametrize istream extraction like that.  It would be cool to be proven wrong though :)

Try this:

```
void input(std::istream &in = std::cin)
{
char t;
in >> t >> X >> t >> Y >> t >> Z >> t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a string as an input in that way.  You will need to use something like

```
char c;
cin.get() >> c;
if (c != '(') throw SomeError;
cin >> X;
cin.get() >> c;
if (c != ',') throw SomeError;
cin >> Y;
```

and so on.

Comment: You usually don't want stream operations to throw.

Answer (score 0):

`basic_istream` is the real class behind `istream` -- the definitions look something like:

```
namespace std { 
typedef basic_istream<char> istream;
typedef basic_ostream<char> istream;
typedef basic_istream<wchar_t> wistream;
typedef basic_ostream<wchar_t> wostream;
}
```

As to why you're getting the error message in the first place, the problem is pretty clearly with parts like:

```
some_istream >> "(";
```

You *seem* to want to read a character, and have it match that against an opening parenthesis, and (probably) fail if that's not what it finds. For better or worse, however, `istream`s don't really support that directly. To do it, you could do something like this:

```
char ch;
some_istream >> ch;
if (ch != '(')
   // handle failure
```

Alternatively, you could just read a character, and *assume* it's what should be there without checking. This can also allow somewhat more flexible input formatting, so "1 2 3" would be accepted just as well as "(1, 2, 3)". For some cases (e.g., input entered directly by a person) that can be fairly helpful. In other cases (e.g., input from another program) any deviation in the input signals a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
in >> "("
```

Conceptually, this makes no sense. You're trying to read input into a string literal. (That's like trying to read input into the constant `5`.) The error is because a string literal is a const array of characters (hence the `const char[2]` type) and so cannot be read into.

You might want this:

```
void input(std::istream &in = std::cin)
{
    char dummy = 0;
    in >> dummy >> X >> dummy >> Y >> dummy >> Z >> dummy;
}
```

All this does is read those characters into a dummy variable. It works, but those characters could be anything.

Rather, you should probably do the following:

```
// if you do it more than once, make it a function
bool expect_char(std::istream& in, char expected)
{
    char check = 0;
    in >> check;

    if (check != expected)
    {
        in.putback(); // replace it
        in.clear(std::ios::failbit); // set fail bit

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void input(std::istream &in = std::cin)
{
    if (!in) // if stream is bad, just return
        return; 

    if (!expect_char(in, '('))
        return;

    in >> X;

    if (!expect_char(in, ','))
        return;

    in >> Y;

    if (!expect_char(in, ','))
        return;

    in >> Z;

    if (!expect_char(in, ')'))
        return;
}
```

Now the only problem is that if extraction fails half-way, we have modified the point object. Ideally, it would be all or nothing. We store intermediate values, then copy them when it all works:

```
void input(std::istream &in = std::cin)
{
    if (!in)
        return; 

    if (!expect_char(in, '('))
        return;

    int newX; // or whatever type it is
    in >> newX;

    if (!expect_char(in, ','))
        return;

    int newY;
    in >> newY;

    if (!expect_char(in, ','))
        return;

    int newZ;
    in >> newZ;

    if (!expect_char(in, ')'))
        return;

    X = newX;
    Y = newY;
    Z = newZ;
}
```

And we get what we were after.

Comment: Mhmm. I'm sure I posted a class reading a special character from an istream here just the other day, but now I can't find it. (Searching SO really sucks. No full-text search capabilities except google, and that doesn't allow a data range.)